# Isotope Search Filter almost figured out

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Need some help with the last bit of it...

I have a fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/2pasq/embedded/result/)**...

I have the filtered searches by button click, and the search by keyword. They work independently, but I can't seem to get them to work together.

**I think the function lies somewhere in here, but I'm a bit lost...**

```
function isotopeSearch(kwd)
{
    // reset results arrays
    var matches = [];
    var misses = [];

    $('.item').removeClass('match miss'); // get rid of any existing classes
    $('#noMatches').hide(); // ensure this is always hidden when we start a new query

    if ( (kwd != '') && (kwd.length >= 2) ) { // min 2 chars to execute query:

        // loop through brands array        
        _.each(items, function(item){
            if ( item.first.indexOf(kwd) !== -1 ) { // keyword matches element
                matches.push( $('#'+item.id)[0] );
            } else {
                misses.push( $('#'+item.id)[0] );
            }
        });

        // add appropriate classes and call isotope.filter
        $(matches).addClass('match');
        $(misses).addClass('miss');
        $container.isotope({ filter: $(matches) }); // isotope.filter will take a jQuery object instead of a class first as an argument - sweet!

        if (matches.length == 0) {
            $('#noMatches').show(); // deal with empty results set
        }

    } else {
        // show all if keyword less than 2 chars
        $container.isotope({ filter: '.item' });
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** I'm trying to make it searchable only by first/last name.

Comment: Can you add isotope to your fiddle?

Comment: I just checked the fiddle. It's in a file called plugins.js. I had the external files on a server requiring authentication. I moved them to a different directory. You should be able to view the fiddle now. You'll find the updated fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/2pasq/12/embedded/result/)

Comment: And thanks for trying to get into this with me!

Comment: The selector being generated is incorrect. I will see if I can figure it out shortly.

Comment: You have a couple of invalid HTML in your JSFiddle... you need to check the red highlights in the HTML window and fix those. I think the trailing `data` at the end of an anchor is causing the red.

Answer (score 0):

It basically looks like your `"*"` selectors are causing the problem on a couple of `All` buttons. If you simply make them blanks "" it seems to work.

I put this alert in your code and noticed the selectors got a little weird after a few selections:

```
    var selector = isoFilters.join('');
    alert(selector);
```

You wound up with selectors like `**.ar`

### JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2pasq/14/

There is not a full set of item values to test all combinations, but it seems to work if you drop the two "*" filters.

Comment: The only HTML in red was a `<section>` tag, but I removed it. Not sure how it got there... The filters seem to work on my end. I get js dialogs when I run your fiddle.  And, again, the filter part works great for me on the full blow site. I have another page where I've incorporated the keyword search, but I want them to co-exist on the same page... so I can be able to sort by the various positions/titles labeled on the buttons, or search by name. Does that make sense? Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/2pasq/15/embedded/result/)